# PHP - Showing time only with interval 5 minutes

Tags: php

i need showing time only with interval 5 minutes, for example :

the time now is 00:00, so its showing **00:00**
at 00:01, its should be still showing **00:00**
at 00:02, its should be still showing **00:00**

the time now is 00:05, so its showing **00:05**
at 00:06, its should be still showing **00:05**
at 00:07, its should be still showing **00:05**

and so on

please help if you can what is the code looks like? gbu for helping

Comment: you just want to substract `($time % (5 * 60))`? (`$time` being an unix timestamp)

Comment: Please provide more information on the topic. You cannot to this client-side with PHP. Limiting the returned to in a function to 5min steps is easy. We need more infomrations on the environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$time = '00:02';

list($h, $m) = explode(':', $time);

$m = (int) $m;
$m -= $m % 5;
$m = sprintf('%02d', $m);

echo implode(':', [$h, $m]);
```